# How to run query affecting entities during a transaction

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am trying to loop through some entities and update the `step_order` column, and then subtract a value from that column after. Take the following example:

1. Start with these entities

   ```
   ID | step_order
   1  | 1
   2  | 2
   3  | 3
   4  | 4
   ```
2. Change the order

   ```
   ID | step_order
   1  | 6
   2  | 5
   3  | 7
   4  | 8
   ```
3. Subtract 4 from order to take the values back to 1

   ```
   ID | step_order
   1  | 2
   2  | 1
   3  | 3
   4  | 4
   ```

This is my code with irrelevant parts removed:

Within manager

```
$nextOrder = $this->stepRepo->findNextOrder($maintenanceId);
$steps = [];
foreach ($order as $o => $stepId) {
    $step = $this->getStep($stepId);
    $steps[] = $step;
}
$this->em->beginTransaction();
foreach ($steps as $o => $step) {
    $step->setStepOrder($nextOrder + $o);
    $this->em->persist($step);
}
$this->stepRepo->subtractOrder($maintenanceId, $nextOrder - 1);
$this->em->commit();
$this->em->flush();

public function getStep($id)
{
    return $this->stepRepo->find($id);
}
```

Within stepRepo

```
public function subtractOrder($maintenanceId, $amount)
{
    $maintenanceId = (int) $maintenanceId;
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('s');
    $qb->update()
        ->set('s.stepOrder', 's.stepOrder - :amount')
        ->where('s.maintenanceId = :maintenanceId')
        ->setParameter('amount', $amount)
        ->setParameter('maintenanceId', $maintenanceId);
    $result = $qb->getQuery()->execute();
    return $result;
}
```

What I expect to happen is the following:

1. Select MAX(step_order)
2. Start transaction
3. Update step_order for each entity
4. Run query updating all step_orders = step_order - MAX(step_order)
5. commit

What is happening:

1. Select MAX(step_order)
2. Start transaction
3. Run query updating all step_orders = step_order - MAX(step_order)
4. commit

Here is the output of the symfony profiler:

```
SELECT MAX(l0_.step_order) AS sclr_0 FROM lsp_maintenance_step l0_ WHERE l0_.maintenance_id = ?
Parameters: ['1']

"START TRANSACTION"
Parameters: { }

UPDATE lsp_maintenance_step SET step_order = step_order - ? WHERE maintenance_id = ?
Parameters: [4, 1]
```

This is the MySQL error:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'UPDATE lsp_maintenance_step SET step_order = step_order - ? WHERE maintenance_id = ?' with params [4, 1]:\n\nSQLSTATE[22003]: Numeric value out of range: 1690 BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range in '(`toolbox`.`lsp_maintenance_step`.`step_order` - 4)'
```

The error is correct, as subtracting 4 from any of the entities will leave step order at 0 or less which is incorrect.

Why is doctrine running the last `UPDATE` before updating the entities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is doctrine running the last `UPDATE` before updating the entities?

After some digging I have found that entities are committed when `flush()` is called on the `EntityManager` whereas `execute()` is ran immediately.

To get around this I used [transaction nesting](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/transactions.html#transaction-nesting), in which the entities are committed in the sub-transaction and the `UPDATE` is called in the main transaction.

```
$this->em->beginTransaction();
try {
    $this->em->beginTransaction();
    try {
        foreach ($steps as $o => $step) {
            $step->setStepOrder($nextOrder + $o);
            $this->em->persist($step);
        }
        $this->em->flush();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->em->rollback();
        throw $e;
    }
    $this->stepRepo->subtractOrder($maintenanceId, $nextOrder - 1);
    $this->em->flush();
    foreach ($steps as $step) {
        $this->em->refresh($step);
    }
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    $this->em->rollback();
}
```

Comment: Remember `persist` only queues up the query.  `flush` actually executes the batch.  So while you're making changes to entities and calling `persist`, only the last change will take affect when calling `flush`.